# Should I rather explicitly run programs in foreground (instead as a daemon), or `expect fork` when configuring upstart daemons?

Tags: unix, upstart, daemon

Many programs allow to be run either in daemon mode (which is usually the default), or explicitly run it in foreground with a flag such as `-f`.

Now when configuring upstart to run programs like this, I can either do

```
exec foo -f # run in foreground
```

or

```
expect fork
exec foo # automatically runs as a daemon
```

Is there a reason to choose one over the other? It feels that it's just easier to run everything in foreground and let upstart handle the processes, but is there a downside to that?

Comment: The answer would depend on end-use, no? The foreground option is often provided as an easy way to debug what the daemon is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly prefer to run things in the foreground; it avoids any complications that may arise from the daemonisation process (such as upstart losing track of the long-running daemon process).  The only exception to this is a small minority of daemonising programs which have the unpleasant habit of interpreting "please run in the foreground" as "please run in some sort of poorly-performing debug mode", and do something silly like run only one thread, or don't spawn child workers, or some such.